# Toggle switch with JS

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to learn some JS, and would like to know if anyone could help me, please.

I would like to do, in a dashboard admin, an control with toggle switch to show on the index of the site whether the service is online or offline.
When on, put a "online" text in a green tag. And when not working, "offline" with a red tag.
How can I do this? With event listener? Thanks!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I7xo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple exaple to show you an approach.

```js
document.getElementById(`status`).addEventListener(`click`, function(){
  const classes = this.classList;
  if (classes.contains(`offline`)) {
    this.textContent = `Online`;
    classes.remove(`offline`);
    classes.add(`online`);
  } else if (classes.contains(`online`)) {
    this.textContent = `Offline`;
    classes.remove(`online`);
    classes.add(`offline`);
  }
});
```

```css
#status {
  color: white;
}

.online {
  background: green;
}

.offline {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span id='status' class='offline'>Offline</span>
```

Comment: Good, bro! Thanks! But this way any user will be able to set the status? I want only admins could do this.

Comment: @AugustoH I see. Well having people on your website with different permissions is a whole different thing entirely. We're talking web-servers and database usage. It's not simple.